# Pesquisar por varios ids API .net core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Nao sei se fui claro no titulo porem tenho uma duvida, possuo uma rota da seguinte forma:

```
/api/produto/v1/Aplicacao/filter
```

onde esse endpoint é um GET que passo uma palavra como parametro e ele faz a busca das palavras que foram passadas.

A duvida é a seguinte, tenho como fazer a rota algo do tipo `/api/produto/v1/Aplicacao/filter/categoria/{id}`, onde o id da categoria fosse opcional e se eu nao passar nada na categoria ele use somente a rota até `/api/produto/v1/Aplicacao/filter` e pesquisa a palavra que foi passada por parametro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução seria passar um id de categoria junto com as palavras na rota `/api/produto/v1/Aplicacao/filter` e, caso esse id seja null, fazer a busca somente pelas palavras.

Para isso, basta criar uma DTO com esses dois campos: uma lista de palavras e uma id de categoria. Essa DTO seria passada como parâmetro no request dentro da controller.

DTO

```
public class YourDto
{
    public List<String> Palavras { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult yourMethodName([FromBody] YourDto dto)
```

Então basta checar se é null o ID e, se for, só fazer a busca por palavras.